# Get first sentence of textview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to get the first sentence of a text view. I have the following code but am getting an out of bounds error. Thank You. Or are there any ways that aren't really complex.

```
   -(IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
    NSRange ran = [[tv.text substringFromIndex:lastLocation] rangeOfString:@". "];
    if(ran.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString * getRidOfFirstHalfString = [[tv.text substringFromIndex:lastLocation] substringToIndex:ran.location];
        NSLog(@"%@",getRidOfFirstHalfString);
        lastLocation+=getRidOfFirstHalfString.length;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alternatively try using NSScanner like this:

```
NSString *firstSentence = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:tv.text];
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:set intoString:&firstSentence];
```

I'm not sure if you want this, but since you want the first sentence, you could append a period (you probably know how to do this, but it doesn't hurt to show it anyway):

```
firstSentence = [firstSentence stringByAppendingFormat:@"."];
```

Hope this helps!

PS: If it didn't work for you, maybe the text view doesn't actually contain any text.

Comment: @BDGapps - Did you NSLog `firstSentence`? I tested it just now and it works perfectly fine. I added a screenshot showing it works.

Comment: i no what i did. i added the text in the nib instead of in code. thanx

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
NSString *finalString = [[tv.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0] // Get the 1st part (left part) of the separated string
```

Go through the textview's text and divide the text into separate components where you find a period by calling `componentsSeperatedByString` on `tv.text`. You want the **first** sentence, which would be the 0th object in the array.

Answer (score 4):

I know you've already accepted an answer to this question, but you might want to consider using the text view's `tokenizer` instead of just searching for the string `". "`  The tokenizer will automatically handle punctuation like `!`, `?`, and closing quotes.  You can use it like this:

```
id<UITextInputTokenizer> tokenizer = textView.tokenizer;
UITextRange *range = [tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument
    withGranularity:UITextGranularitySentence
    inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionForward];
NSString *firstSentence = [textView textInRange:range];
```

If you want to enumerate all of the sentences, you can do it like this:

```
id<UITextInputTokenizer> tokenizer = textView.tokenizer;
UITextPosition *start = textView.beginningOfDocument;
while (![start isEqual:textView.endOfDocument]) {
    UITextPosition *end = [tokenizer positionFromPosition:start toBoundary:UITextGranularitySentence inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionForward];
    NSString *sentence = [textView textInRange:[textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end]];
    NSLog(@"sentence=%@", sentence);
    start = end;
}
```

Comment: what would i do if i wanted the second sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking that the substring was actually found.

```
NSRange ran = [tv.text rangeOfString:@". "];
if(ran.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSString * selectedString = [tv.text substringToIndex:ran.location];
    NSLog(@"%@",selectedString);
}
```